# MongoDB: What is the effect of document size on collection scan performance and "working set" memory footprint?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking at splitting a collection of "sizable" documents into 2 collections (often queried summary fields, and never queried detail fields/arrays of documents). The aim is to reduce average document size, and therefore reduce "working set" memory footprint and collection scan times. Documents will reduce from ~9.5kB to ~2.7kB a reduction of 3.5x (in memory BSON size).

This should reduce requirements on the wiredTiger cache by the same 3.5x factor and therefore require 3.5x less memory in the machine. Will it also speed up collection scan queries by a similar amount? Update / insert operations are rare and NOT performance critical, because run in offline batch processes.

This is for MongoDB 4 running on FreeBSD. The web application is in php7.3, but that's not really relevant.

I currently have 1million documents at above sizes. This is about 3.5GB on disk and 7GB in memory after decompressing. Current server has 16GB RAM, but this is becoming an issue and is part of the motivation, since the number of documents is expected to grow quickly to 4million and then more slowly to 8million.

The application is primarily a "slice and dice" query interface. About 20 different "filters" in the UI driving query conditions on the various summary fields. All of them are indexed, including some compound and some multi-key for small arrays, but because the "UI filters" can be used in any combination, indexes cannot always help as it is not realistic to create compound indexes for every possible field combination.

The structure of the collection documents is 5 large arrays of detail sub-documents (these make up ~70% of the total document size), plus a number of computed "summary fields". The summary fields are computed from the large detail sub-documents in a slow, offline process. This is fine and not the issue. The queries are ONLY against the summary fields, never against the original sub-documents. But we end up with regular "full collection scans". These are beginning to slow down as collection size grows. Currently ~10s when no index available and result includes almost the full collection. This is too slow to be truly interactive. Counts are critical to the application, and again they often require complete collection scans. We have done what we can with "covered queries" including for the counts.

The proposal is to store the original detail sub-documents in a separate collection "linked" by _id. "Lookup joins" will never be needed, except during background batch processing which is not time critical. Updates are extremely rare.

We have analysed the proportion of the collection which is made up of the original sub-documents and moving them off into a separate (and rarely accessed) collection will reduce average document size by factor of 3.5x.

We expect that this will reduce wiredTiger cache size requirements by the same factor and therefore reduces our physical hardware RAM scaling requirements.

The question is: Will we also see a reduction in query execution time when a collection scan is required, because the CPU is only scanning through much lighter documents? Will any gain here be of a similar order of magnitude, ie ~3.5x?

Or is this a false hope, because BSON structure allows wiredTiger to skip past all the "dead wood" in each document. If that's the case, there might still be a smaller gain due to CPU on die cache? ie the smaller documents will be more in contiguous memory?

Comment: Smaller documents should absolutely result in a speedup. Because there's more of them in the same space (memory page, disk sector, etc.) The more compact they are, the less storage reads are needed (cache access is still slower than no access). As to the magnitude, this needs to be measured, of course.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks. That's an encouraging validation of my thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now done this collection split. Result is good:

- Memory footprint of mongod reduced by ~3.4x as expected
- collection scan speed also significantly faster (around ~3x)

So, if you have a large collection (many documents) with a significant average document size due to sizeable sub-arrays/documents, and those sub-arrays/documents are rarely needed for queries (ie not too many $lookups or similar), then splitting them out into a separate collection can be very worthwhile.

Lower RAM requirements AND faster collection scans by roughly the factor that you manage to reduce the avg doc size by.