# MongoDB: reduce read size and RAM needed with project?

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-design, mongodb-query, ram

I am designing a MongoDB database that looks something like this:

```
registry:{
id:1,
duration:123,
score:3,
text:"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
}
```

The text field is very big compared to the rest. I sometimes need to perform analytics queries that average the duration or the score, but never use the text.
I have queries that are more specific, and retrieve all the information about a single document. But in this queries I could spend more time making two queries to retrieve all the data.
My question is, if I make a query like this:

```
db.registries.aggregate( [
  {
    $group: {
       _id: null,
       averageDuration: { $avg: "$duration" },
    }
  }
] )
```

Would it need to read the data from the transcript field? That would make the query much slower and it would take a lot of RAM. If that is the case it would be better to split the records in two and have something like this right?:

```
registry:{
id:1,
duration:123,
score:3,
}  


registry_text:{
id:1,
text:"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Splitting works well in some cases. [stackoverflow.com/questions/56734065/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734065/mongodb-what-is-the-effect-of-document-size-on-collection-scan-performance-and)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the server works in this case but I expect that, for caching reasons, the server will load complete documents into memory when it reads them from disk. Disk reads are very slow (= expensive in time taken) and I expect server will aggressively use memory if it can to avoid reads.

An important note here is that the documents are stored on disk as lists of key-value pairs comprising their contents. To *not* load a field from disk the server would have to rebuild the document in question as part of reading it since there are length fields involved. I don't see this happening in practice.

So, once the documents are in memory I assume they are there with all of their fields and I don't expect you can tune this.

When you are querying, the server may or may not drop individual fields but this would only change the memory requirements for the particular query. Generally these memory requirements are dwarfed by the overall database cache size and aggregation pipelines. So I don't think it really *matters* at what point a large field is dropped from a document during query processing (assuming you project it out in the query).

I think this isn't a worthwhile matter to try to ponder/optimize. If you have a real system with real workloads, you'll be much more pressed to optimize something else.

If you are concerned with memory usage when the amount of available memory is consumer-sized (say, under 16 gb), just get more memory - it's insanely cheap given how much time you'd spend working around lack of it (whether we are talking about provisioning bigger AWS instances or buying more sticks of RAM).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `$project` to limit the fields read.

As a general advice, don't try to normalize the data with MongoDB as you would with SQL. Also, it's often more performant to read documents plain from DB and do the processing on your server.

Comment: ok, so by using project I do not read all the columns and the size of the query will be small right?  
You mean that I get all the registries and perform the average, sums... in my servers? are not databases supposed to be optimized for that?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this answer that seems to indicate that project needs to fetch all document in the database server, it only reduces bandwith

> When using projection to remove unused fields, the MongoDB server will
>   have to fetch each full document into memory (if it isn't already
>   there) and filter the results to return. This use of projection
>   doesn't reduce the memory usage or working set on the MongoDB server,
>   but can save significant network bandwidth for query results depending
>   on your data model and the fields projected.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198444/how-mongodb-projection-affects-performance

Comment: I will wait a day or two in case someone has something to add to this issue, or states that new versions of mongo work differently and I will close the question